# Server.MapPath inside a MVC app with Blazor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, blazor-server-side

I've got a MVC 6.0 app, without startup.cs, that I've added Blazor to. I need to get Server.MapPath inside one of my Blazor components. The Blazor's code doesn't have a constructor so I can't inject into it.

The reason is i've got a font file in my Data folder that I need to turn into a stream so my pdf generator can use it. I can't seem to get a path to that file.

Any thoughts?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to inject `IWebHostEnvironment` env into my Blazor Server page. In the code-behind partial class I added:

```
 private  IWebHostEnvironment? _env;
 _env = Env;
```

This gave me access to the `ContentRootPath`.